# Error Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de enviar dos array a mi BD, un array de actividades y otro array de puntos!! asii el formulario, y el error que me lanza es un array to string conversion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque, me podrían ayudar?

el error 1/2 es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí el código del html:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="detalle.actividad_id" ng-model="puntuacion.detalle.actividad_id" ng-options="actividad.id as actividad.nombre for actividad in actividades | filter:{ circular_id: puntuacion.detalle.circular_id, tipo_a_id: 1}"></select> 
<input ng-repeat="actividad in actividades | filter:{ circular_id: puntuacion.detalle.circular_id, tipo_a_id: 1}" type="text" class="form-control"  name="detalle.puntos[]" ng-model="puntuacion.detalle.puntos[$index]" placeholder="@{{ actividad.puntuacion }}">
```

y el código en el controlador laravel:

```
$datos = $request->detalle;
   foreach ($datos  as $key => $value) {
       $d = new Detalle();
       $d->puntuacion_id = $puntuacion->id;
       $actividad_id = $value;
       $d->actividad_id = $request->detalle['actividad_id'];
       $puntos = $request->puntos[$key];
       $d->puntos = $request->detalle['puntos'];

        $d->save();
    }
```

los datos quiero que se almacenen por fila, así es la estructura de la tabla detalles, son varias filas que quiero registrar de una vez y por eso utilizo un select multiple y varios inputs! pero creo que el error está en la lógica del controlador, me pueden ayudar?? por favor!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la parte 1/2 del error? ¿cómo deseas almacenar los dos array en la base de datos? ¿qué motor de bases de datos utilizas?

Comment: son varias actividades que quiero registrar a la vez y por eso utilizo un select multiple, y registrar varios puntos a la vez con un ngRepeat de inputs... y estoy usando mysql y como que te muestre la mitad del error?

Comment: No es la mitad del error, si te fijas... ahí dice 2/2, es porque Laravel muestra  dos errores, y ese es el segundo, el otro es el 1/2 y está más abajo. Me puedes indicar al menos como quieres almacenar los valores? separados por coma, o no sé que formato desees.

Comment: ah ya entendii, disculpa soy nueva en esto! ya edite la pregunta, está mejor así?

Comment: Sí gracias, ahora me puedes responder en qué formato deseas almacenar los arrays?

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, cuando se resuelva el problema quisiera saber a qué se deben esos caracteres algo extraños      (`l̺̿i̺̿n̺̿g̺̿`)    en el nombre del OP. Saludos.

Comment: int actividad_id[] e int puntos[]

Comment: Tienes un campo int en la base de datos, pero tienes un array, por lo cual no puedes almacenar esos dos o más valores en un solo campo. Ejemplo: 75 y 200 son los dos valores de puntos, ¿cómo deseas almacenarlos?

Comment: en campos distintos.. en el mismo campo no!! son varias filas que quiero que genere, me entiendes?

Comment: Una vez resuelto el problema, quiero saber qué significan los caracteres que se ven en tu nombre, primera vez que veo algo así. Saludos.

Comment: no tienen ningun significado, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes hacer el foreach en los dos campos respectivos, no en todo el request, sin embargo considero que la forma como lo estás planteando no es la ideal.

Este método asume que tienes la misma cantidad de valores en actividades y en puntos:

```
$datos = $request->detalle;

$d = new Detalle();
$d->puntuacion_id = $puntuacion->id;

foreach ($datos['actividad_id'] as $index => $actividad) {
    $d->actividad_id = $actividad;
    $d->puntos = $datos['puntos'][$index];
    $d->save();
}
```

En este caso tendrías dos registros nuevos en la base de datos, el primero con actividad 22 y puntos 75, y el segundo con actividad 23 y puntos 200.

Answer (score 0):

El error 2/2

Parámetros de tipo timestamp llevan comillas, y estas intentando ingresarlas sin,

Error 1/2 es porque estas pasando arrays en la query, no un string como deberias.

- ***6.***

'22',**array('22','33')**,**array('75','200')**,'2017-09-05 02:35:20','2017-09-05 02:35:20'

Segundo y tercer parámetro estas pasando arrays con dos valores cada uno, prueba con nombreDeLaVariable[0] para pasar '22' en vez de array('22','33') en el segundo parámetro

Comment: el nombreDeLaVariable[0] en este caso sería así: $actividad_id[$key] = $value;

Comment: listoo, solo tuve que cambiar el ciclo foreach por ciclo el while!

Comment: Es falso lo que explicas del error 2/2, además de esa forma no resolverías el problema del error 1/2 pues estaría descartando los demás valores. -1