# Función AJAX no retorna nada

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

tengo una función AJAX que es similar al proyecto que estoy haciendo pero a diferencia esta no retorna la fila que estoy tratando de llamar de la base de datos.

**Codigo AJAX**

```
$(".btnData").click(function() {

    var idLote = $(this).attr("idData");
    console.log(idLote);
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("loT", idLote);

    $.ajax({
        url: "views/ajax/OITData.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        //async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log("AJAX", respuesta);

        }
    });

});
```

**Archivo que recibe el AJAX**

```
<?php

require_once "../../controllers/gestorTablaOIT.php";
require_once "../../models/gestorTablaOIT.php";


#CLASES
#**********************************************************************

class Ajax{

   #TRAE LA FILA DEPENDIENDO DEL LOTE
    #******************************************************************


        public $loteBus;

        public function traerData(){

        $datos = array("Elote" => $this -> loteBus);
        $respuesta=GestorTabla::obtenerDataController($datos);
        echo json_encode($respuesta);

   }
}

#OBJETOS
#************************************************************************


if(isset($_POST['loT'])){
    $a = new Ajax();
    $a -> loteBus = $_POST['loT'];
    $a -> traerData();

}

?>
```

**Pasa al controlador**

```
public function obtenerDataController($datos){
        $respuesta=GestorTablaModels::mostrarElementIDTModel($datos, "cajas");
        echo $respuesta;
    }
```

**Por ultimo llega al modelo donde se ejecuta el codigo para traer la fila de la base de datos**

```
public function mostrarElementIDTModel($datos, $tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT* FROM $tabla WHERE n_lote=:idLote");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":idLote", $datos["Elote"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt -> fetch();
        $stmt->close();

    }
```

Cualquier ayuda lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Tal vez no hay registros en tu tabla que matcheen la query ¿Revisaste el log de errores del servidor? Aparte de esto, deberias cerrar el statement antes de salir de la funcion, sino es en vano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas razones por las que una petición AJAX puede no enviar información, ya sea por un error del lado del cliente (cuando se formula la petición) o por un error en el lado del servidor (en los archivos php).

Dicho lo anterior solo queda investigar dónde se está produciendo el error.

Para ello yo realizo dos cosas:
1.- Checar la consola del navegador, si existe un error del lado del cliente se va a mostar en esa sección.
Y una vez ahí adentro también reviso la sección de red del inspector del navegador, en mi caso uso Firefox y tiene un aspecto similar al de la imagen:

[image: Inspector web de Firefox]

En esta sección puedes saber el estado de cada petición y el código de respuesta de la misma. Con ello ya puedes tener una idea un poco más clara del problema.

2.- Checar los archivos log del servidor.
Si hay algún error en el lado del servidor aparecerá en esta sección.
Si estas en un servidor local este archivo suele llamarse "error_log" o algo por el estilo y se encuentran regularmente en la ruta: "MAMP/logs/php_error.log". (En mi caso yo uso mamp server, pero si usas otro servidor la ruta debe de ser similar).
En el caso de los hosting o los servidores regularmente debe de haber una carpeta en la raíz de tu servidor que se llame "error_logs" o algo similar, y ahí deberán de aparecer todos los errores de php.

Espero te sea de ayuda esta información.

Comment: Revisando la sección de red me da este error que no muestra la consola
`<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Empaque\controllers\gestorTablaOIT.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br />` en el "echo" de respuesta del controlador
Arraynull

Comment: Puede que el siguiente artículo te pueda ayudar:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99886/error-array-to-string-conversion