# Guardar array en string Laravel

Tags: laravel, array, fileupload

Estoy realizando la carga de multiples imagenes y al querer guardar la ruta de las mismas recibo el siguiente error:

> Array to string conversion

Estoy utilizando Laravel livewire pero entiendo que es lo mismo que sólo con Laravel, mi código es el siguente:

**Vista**

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

**Componente**

```
use WithFileUploads;
public $imagenes = [];


foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGalería) {
       $pathGalería->store('imagenesPropiedades');
}

$properties = Property::create([

    'imagenes' => $this->imagenes

]);
```

**ARRAY**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo guardar el array de rutas en la variable de string?

**EDICIÓN**

```
       foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGalería) {
            $pathImagenes = $pathGalería->store('imagenesPropiedades');
            $properties = Property::create([
                'imagenes' => $pathImagenes
            ]);
        }

        
        $properties = Property::create([

        'user_id' => $this->usuarioId,
        'tipoDePropiedad_id' => $this->tipo_de_propiedad,
        'ubicacion_id' =>   $this->ubicacionSeleccionada,
        'area_id' =>    $this->area,
        'category_id' =>    $this->categoria,           

        'direccion_propiedad' =>    $this->direccion_propiedad,
        'nombre_propiedad' =>   $this->nombre_propiedad,
        'descripcion_propiedad' =>  $this->descripcion_propiedad,
        'detalle_propiedad' => $detallePropiedadCorto,
        'mapa_propiedad' =>     $this->mapa,
        'codigo' =>     $this->codigo,
        'moneda' =>     $this->moneda,
        'precio_propiedad' =>   $this->precio_propiedad,
        'precio_expensas_propiedad' =>  $this->expensas_propiedad,
        'slug_propiedad' => $resultadoSlug,
        'video' =>  $this->video,
        'recorrido' =>  $this->recorrido,
        'cantidad_ambientes' =>     $this->ambientes,
        'dormitorios' =>    $this->dormitorios,
        'banos' =>  $this->banos,
        'cocheras' =>   $this->cocheras,
        'antiguedad' =>     $this->antiguedad,
        'status' => 'APROBADO',
        'anuncio' => 'GRATIS',
        'mt2desde' => $this->mt2desde,
        'mt2hasta' => $this->mt2hasta,
        'portada' => asset($path)

        ]);
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error Array to string conversion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99886/error-array-to-string-conversion)

Comment: Me puedes brindar una idea más de como se haría en mi caso? $this->imagenes tiene las rutas y mueve las imágenes en base a la temporal. Edito la pregunta con el array devuelto, por que no es como en Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está específicamente en esta línea:

```
$properties = Property::create([
    'imagenes' => $this->imagenes
]);
```

Dado que la columna `imagenes` es un string y tu variable `$this->imagenes` es un array. Por eso obtienes dicho error.

Imagino que quieres crear un registro por imagen, por ende, tu `create()` debería estar dentro de `foreach`.

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGalería) {
     $path = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

     $properties = Property::create([
       'imagenes' => $path
     ]);
}
```

Comment: Buenas! en realidad necesito crear un array con los datos de una sóla vez. De esta manera obtengo un error **doesn't have a default value** por que ya tengo un create estructurado. Voy a agregar mi create a ver si me puedes brindar una idea más. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Es posible hacer un update? lo que no me doy cuenta como puedo indicar que el update es del create previo.

Comment: En una tabla puedes guardar sólo *una* imagen. Si quieres guardar muchas imágenes necesitarás una nueva tabla llamada "Imágenes por categoría"

Comment: Me trajo algunos problemas la tabla polimorfica imageable a veces se guardan registros mal por eso quise agregar en la misma tabla el campo url. Y en formato JSON algo así crees que no es conveniente: json_encode($this->imagenes); ¿tu harías una tabla nueva antes que esto? gracias como siempre!!!

Comment: Yo crearía una nueva tabla, pero lo que dices funcionará, si tu array lo conviertes a un json entonces podrás guardarlo como un string en una sola columna. Prueba eso.

Comment: Voy a seguir tu consejo de la tabla nueva por que me doy cuenta que requiere hasta 50 imágenes y eso puede ser ilegible en la misma tabla. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Disculpá cerre la pregunta pero tengo una duda, te puedo preguntar aquí mismo o debería crear otra pregunta nueva?